# How to pass input value from one component to the other component( where api & data display code are )? how to make connection between 2 components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-props, react-state

**I have two components where one comp provides a search input field where the user will enter data(e.g; city name) and another comp provides the main weather data( based on the user search input from comp 1) like temp, wind, etc.. how should I pass the user input to the API so it will render the data of that city. I have been stuck on this issue for the last 3 days. any solution?**

**Comp1 (search comp)**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../Componentstyle/search.css";
export default function Search() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();
  
const handlesubmit = (event)=>{
  event.preventDefault();
  setLocation(event.target.value)
}
  return (
    <>
    <div className="main">
      <nav className="istclass">
        <form className="form">
          <div className="search">
            <input
              value={location}
              placeholder="search city"
              className="searchbox"
              onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
            />

            <button className="nd" type="button" onClick={handlesubmit}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </nav>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Comp2 (maindata comp)**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../Componentstyle/Main.css";
export default function Maindata() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();


  let city = "mansehra";

  let weather = async () => {
    // if(!city)return;
    const key = "XYZ";
    await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${key}&units=metric&formatted=0`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((actualData) => setData(actualData));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    weather();
  }, []);

  if (!data) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  const link = `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`;

  return (
    <>
    <div className="maindata">
      <div className="city">{data.name}</div>
      <div className="temp">{data.main.temp} C</div>
      <div className="icon">
        <img src={link} alt="not found" />{" "}
      </div>
      <div className="feel">feels Like {data.main.feels_like} C</div>
      <div className="wind">Wind {data.wind.speed} Km/hr</div>
      <div className="cloudy">{data.weather[0].main}</div>
      <div className="humidity">humidity {data.main.humidity}%</div>
      <div className="sunrise">
        sunrise :- {new Date(data.sys.sunrise * 1000).toUTCString()}{" "}
      </div>
      <div className="sunset">
        sunset :- {new Date(data.sys.sunset * 1000).toUTCString()}
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**App.js Comp**

```
import "./App.css";
import Maindata from "./Components/Maindata";
import Search from "./Components/Search";



function App() {
  
  return (
    <div className="mainpage">
      <div className="searchComp">
        <Search />
      </div>
      <div className="details">
        <Maindata />

  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Move the `Search` component's state up to a common ancestor component and pass the state and state updater callback function down as props to the components needing them.

Example:

App

```
function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="mainpage">
      <div className="searchComp">
        <Search {...{ location, setLocation }} />
      </div>
      <div className="details">
        <Maindata city={location} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Search

```
export default function Search({ location, setLocation }) {
  const handlesubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setLocation(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <nav className="istclass">
        <form className="form">
          <div className="search">
            <input
              value={location}
              placeholder="search city"
              className="searchbox"
              onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
            />

            <button className="nd" type="button" onClick={handlesubmit}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Maindata

```
export default function Maindata({ city = "mansehra" }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const weather = async (city) => {
    const key = "XYZ";
    await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${key}&units=metric&formatted=0`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((actualData) => setData(actualData));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (city) {
      weather(city); // <-- pass city through to function
    }
  }, [city]);

  if (!data) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  const link = `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`;

  return (
    <>
    <div className="maindata">
      <div className="city">{data.name}</div>
      <div className="temp">{data.main.temp} C</div>
      <div className="icon">
        <img src={link} alt="not found" />{" "}
      </div>
      <div className="feel">feels Like {data.main.feels_like} C</div>
      <div className="wind">Wind {data.wind.speed} Km/hr</div>
      <div className="cloudy">{data.weather[0].main}</div>
      <div className="humidity">humidity {data.main.humidity}%</div>
      <div className="sunrise">
        sunrise :- {new Date(data.sys.sunrise * 1000).toUTCString()}{" "}
      </div>
      <div className="sunset">
        sunset :- {new Date(data.sys.sunset * 1000).toUTCString()}
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Nice. This is simpler than the solution I proposed. I didn't read the question carefully enough and had thought these were two separate pages / routes. That said, putting the value into a context might be more scalable as the OP might end up using the value on other pages / routes when the application grows.

Comment: @NeilGirardi Agreed, that is an accurate point. It's my opinion when teaching/helping others to start with the basics. "Lifting State Up" is a design pattern, i.e. co-locate some "common state" and pass down as props. The React Context API is an applied implementation of this pattern to solve the issue of props drilling when the common ancestor and consuming children get spread throughout the ReactTree.

Comment: Thanks for the help but there is one problem coming with your answer(code). In API, {city} is undefined and bcz of that all data is not rendering...any idea? or solution?

Comment: @AhsanKhalid Did you pass the `location` state in `App` on the `city` prop, i.e. `<Maindata city={location} />`? Interestingly enough, the code in my answer the `city` prop is also given a default prop value of `"mansehra"` in the case a `city` prop isn't passed or is undefined.

Comment: yes, I did pass the state but it's not working.

Comment: what could be the problem you think?

Comment: @AhsanKhalid Oh, I'm sorry, I forgot to pass `city` through to the `weather` function. It should be working now, please check again. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-pass-input-value-from-one-component-to-the-other-component-where-api-d-3tvz33) demo.

Comment: It might be irritating for you but I'm sorry to ask that please check in the demo above that when I type a letter, it stops rendering the page. else everything works fine thanks for that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249209/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-ahsan-khalid).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the context API. You would create a context for location. The context's provider would wrap both the search component as well as the component that performs the API call (MainData?) You would set the context value in the search component and get the context value in the MainData component.

The `LocationProvider` could look like this:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'

export const LocationContext = createContext(null)

const LocationProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [ location, setLocation ] = useState('')
  return (
    <LocationContext.Provider value={{location, setLocation}}>
      {children}
    </LocationContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default LocationProvider
```

If both components are wrapped in this provider, you can access `setLocation()` in the `SearchComponent` by importing `LocationContext` and then doing this:

```
const { setLocation } = useContext(LocationContext)
```

and in the other component you can access the location in a similar manner:

```
const { location } = useContext(LocationContext)
```

Comment: Should I have to make an extra component for this Context code ?                               
 `import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'

export const LocationContext = createContext(null)

const LocationProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [ location, setLocation ] = useState('')
  return (
    <LocationContext.Provider value={{location, setLocation}}>
      {children}
    </LocationContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default LocationProvider`

Comment: Yes. You can use the component I posted in my Answer. It should wrap the components that use the context. Given the structure of your `App `component, it could wrap around `<div className='mainpage'/>`